# Google Drive API v3. Export doc and preserve comments

Tags: go, google-drive-api

I'm trying to export google doc to both odt and docx formats.

When I export through the site, exported files contain all the comments.

But when I use golang api `service.Files.Export(f.Id, mimeType).Context(ctx).Download()` file content is exported fine, but all comments are lost.

Can I export files with comments through google api?

Comment: In my environment, when a Google Document including the comments is exported with `service.Files.Export(f.Id, mimeType).Context(ctx).Download()` as the mimeType of `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document`, the exported DOCX file has the comments. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. So can I ask you about the method for replicating your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't related to the API.

User has to have read/write access to a file in order to view or export comments. Readonly users don't see comments at all.